# How to display the list of courses in this interface?

Tags: java

I am currently developing a Java application that allows student to register for courses.
I wanna ask that how should I display the list of courses in the following interface?
Should I connect the fxml file with my database?
And also I wish to use linked list to allow the students in searching the courses,may i ask how to do it? shall i also connect the database with the linked list?If yes, how should I connect?

The code of linked list is given as below:

```
import java.util.*;
public class searchCourseTesting
{ 
    public static void main( String [] args ) 
    { 
        List<courseList> list = Arrays.asList
        (
    try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","SYSTEM","12345");
            Statement stmt= conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select STUDENT_NAME from STUDENT where STUDENT_YEAR_ENROLLED=2019");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
        );

        List<courseList> result = searchIn
        ( list, 
            new Matcher<courseList>() 
            { 
                public boolean matches( courseList c ) 
                { 
                    return c.getCourse().toLowerCase().contains("of".toLowerCase());
                }
            }
        );

      System.out.println( result );
    }

    public static <T> List<T> searchIn( List<T> list , Matcher<T> m ) 
    { 
        List<T> r = new ArrayList<T>();
        for( T t : list ) 
        { 
            if( m.matches( t ) ) 
            { 
                r.add( t );
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
}

class courseList 
{ 
    String course;

    String getCourse()
    { 
        return course;
    }

    static courseList add( String course ) 
    { 
        courseList c = new courseList();
        c.course = course;
        return c;
    }
    public String toString() 
    { 
        return String.format("%s", course);
        //String = String.replaceAll(", $", "");
    }    
}

interface Matcher<T> 
{ 
    public boolean matches( T t );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gILW.png)

Comment: Which "linked list" are you talking about? What is the purpose of your `courseList` class? It makes no sense.

Comment: the "linked list" is provided as above, its purpose is to allow the students to search for a particular course in the registration system, and the purpose of the courseList class is to get the name of the courses...and then for the interface you can see the image description,it is okay i will try to work on it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest that you follow Java naming conventions (Class names are capitalized).

A fxml file is used only to display the data and is more or less static. The controller that you appoint to this `Stage` (fxml) is responsible for DB calls or other changes.

What you are trying to do is display the data from your DB on your UI and it is pretty straightforward.

First start by implementing a class that takes care of your DB calls. It should contain (at least) two functions. One to fetch all courses that returns a `List<Course>` so that you can use directly that on your UI. And another one that fetches courses based on a `keyword` that a user gives.

At the moment that your stage is initialized in your controller you should fetch all your courses and display them like this:

```java
@FXML
public void initialize()
{
    YourDatabaseHandler dbHandler = new YourDatabaseHandler();
    
    List<Course> courses = dbHandler.getAllCourses();
    
    listViewOfCourses.getItems().addAll(courses); // ListViewOfCourses should be the listview that you have on your fxml file or controller.
}
```

Then you should add a listener to your search button. Every time the button is clicke, you fetch the filtered content from your DB through the keyword. Here is an example:

```java
@FXML
public void onSearchButtonClicked()// Here either ActionEvent or ClickEvent
{
    YourDatabaseHandler dbHandler = new YourDatabaseHandler();
    String keyword = yourTextField.getText(); // yourTextField should be the search text field
    
    List<Course> courses = dbHandler.getFilteredCourses(keyword);
    
    listViewOfCourses.getItems().clear(); // Remove already added courses
    listViewOfCourses.getItems().addAll(courses); // ListViewOfCourses should be the listview that you have on your fxml file or controller.
}
```

Comment: yesyes! display the data on UI is exactly what i want! so if in this case, do I need linked list if I wish the students to search the courses?

Comment: and also shall I connect my FXML with my database if I want to display the data on the UI?

Comment: I think you should read my answer more thoroughly...

Comment: okay ii think i overlooked some info, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you can do just use a SQL quarry

```
SELECT * FROM courses WHERE Course_name LIKE search_keyward%
```

And show the selected data in recycelview.